# Matlab TreeBagger OOBPrediction flag not recognized

Tags: matlab, random-forest

I'm using the TreeBagger function of Matlab R2015a with the name-value pairs `'OOBPrediction', 'on'` and `'OOBPredictorImportance', 'on'`. Now I'm getting the following error message:

> Invalid parameter name: OOBPrediction.

In the official Matlab documentation this name-value pair is listed.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually seems to be something that has changed between MATLAB R2015a and R2015b.

If you consult the documentation inside your own MATLAB R2015a (using either `help treebagger` or `doc treebagger`), you will get an example where that parameter is used:

> Example:
>
> ```
> load fisheriris
> b = TreeBagger(50,meas,species,'oobpred','on')
> plot(oobError(b))
> xlabel('number of grown trees')
> ylabel('out-of-bag classification error')
> ```

In the [online documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html) and in newer versions of MATLAB, you will find something like:

> Example:
>
> ```
> load fisheriris
> b = TreeBagger(50,meas,species,'OOBPrediction','on')
> plot(oobError(b))
> xlabel('number of grown trees')
> ylabel('out-of-bag classification error')
> ```

**Long story short:**

- Use `oobpred` instead of `OOBPrediction`.
- Consult your local MATLAB documentation for your version of MATLAB, rather than the online one.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I have on my local machine MATLAB R2015b but on the cluster I have R2015a, so I cannot inspect the Matlab documentation. Could you perhaps also tell me the name for `OOBPredictorImportance` in R2015a?

Comment: I suppose that could be `oobvarimp`. In any case, even on a cluster, you can inspect the documentation: just run `str = help('treebagger')` and then `str` will contain the help text which you can pass back to your workstation as you would for your normal data. Also, I think if your company/university has a good contract for MATLAB (for universities, this is often a TAH (total academic headcount) agreement, you can probably inspect the old documentation online if you log in with your Mathworks account)